# How to get all the parents and children of a document in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, mongodb-java

I recently started working on mongodb. My simple application will have Geo hierarchy like

Continet-->Country-->Region--->Resort-->Accommodation

My data will be like this

```
 {
    "_id" : ObjectId("54854d5af2ef42fe7d4d2a44"),
    "name" : "Europe",
    "parent" : "",
    "type" : "Continent",
    "synonym" : "",
    "code" : "EEE"
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("54854d5af2ef42fe7d4d2a47"),
    "name" : "Bulgaria",
    "parent" : "EEE",
    "type" : "Country",
    "synonym" : "",
    "code" : "BGR"
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("54854d5af2ef42fe7d4d2a45"),
    "name" : "Albania",
    "parent" : "EEE",
    "type" : "Country",
    "synonym" : "",
    "code" : "ALB"
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("54854d5af2ef42fe7d4d2a48"),
    "name" : "Bourgas Region",
    "parent" : "BGR",
    "type" : "Region",
    "synonym" : "",
    "code" : "002682"
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("54854d5af2ef42fe7d4d2a49"),
    "name" : "Obzor",
    "parent" : "002682",
    "type" : "Resort",
    "synonym" : "",
    "code" : "002911"
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("54854d5af2ef42fe7d4d2a4a"),
    "name" : "Sunny Beach",
    "parent" : "002682",
    "type" : "Resort",
    "synonym" : "",
    "code" : "002548"
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("54854d5af2ef42fa7d4d2b3d"),
    "name" : "Hotel Park Avenue",
    "parent" : "002548",
    "type" : "Accommodation",
    "synonym" : "",
    "code" : "022548"
}
```

As shown above there will be only the direct parent available in every document.

Now I have to get all the parents and children to a document with  "code" : "002548"

If I have the Resort code, i have to get all the Accommodations which have the respective resort as parent and i have to get the Destination, Country, Continent to which the resort belongs to.

I feel that there should be recursive queries to get this, I am using MongoTemplate for db operations.

Please Help me to get the best solution for this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

mongodb doesn't support joins so you'll have to do multiple queries to walk up that hierarchy.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: What he's looking for are joins which mongo doesn't support.  He'll have to use multiple queries.  that *is* the answer.

Comment: @evanchooly i understand that we have to use multiple queries.... Can you please suggest the best way in using multiple queries logically

Answer (score 0):

It'd be helpful to know what kinds of queries you're running on these documents, but I'm guessing the levels of interest are `Resort` and `Accomodation`. You've structured the higher three levels as separate documents, but it seems to me they are properties of `Resorts` and `Accomodations`: a `Resort` is in a given region, country, continent. Moreover, regions, countries, and continents don't change very  much. I think the higher-level geo information is a good candidate for being embedded in `Resort` and `Accommodation` documents:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("54854d5af2ef42fa7d4d2b3d"),
    "name" : "Hotel Park Avenue",
    "type" : "Accommodation",
    "synonym" : "",
    "code" : "022548",
    "region" : "New York",
    "country" : "United States",
    "continent" : "North America"
}
```

With this kind of structure, finding the "parents" of an accommodation like the above is just looking at the region, country, continent field values. Finding the  "children" of, e.g., a country is a simple query:

```
db.stuff.find({ "country" : "United States" })
```

Comment: The levels of interest are not only accommodations and resorts. I need everything for example if the user searched with country code I wanted to display everything including the continent of that country along with all the regions resorts and accommodations under that country... hope I am clear